# Does the "monotone sequence principle" have an accepted name?

Tags: real-analysis, terminology

A common way of finding the limit of a function at a point is to carefully choose a sequence approaching that point and compute that limit. One way to justify this is:

> "**Monotone Sequence Principle.**" Consider $a,b \in [-\infty,\infty]$ with $a<b$. Suppose $f : (a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is monotone (i.e. it is either non-increasing or non-decreasing.) Then for all increasing sequences $x : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow (a,b)$ whose limit in $[-\infty,\infty]$ is $b$, we have: $$\lim_{i \in \mathbb{N}} f(x_i) = \lim_{x \rightarrow b} f(x).$$
>
> Similarly for the sequence $x : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow (a,b)$ assumed decreasing and with limit $a$, used to compute $\mathrm{lim}_{x \rightarrow a}f(x).$

For example, this is commonly used to compute Hausdorff measures, because $H_{d,\varepsilon}$ is non-increasing in $\varepsilon$.

> **Question.** In the interest of being more explicit, I'd like a name for what I'm calling the "monotone sequence principle" that's understood by a sizeable readership. Is there one?

Comment: *Remark.* I think this is basically saying that every cluster point of the relevant filter is a limit point. Something like that.